# Preselect multiple default (entity) values in Drupal 7 webform

Tags: drupal-7, drupal-webform

I'm trying to write a custom module to pass entity id's from VBO - possibly using a session variable? - to a particular webform so the form's entity-set can be pre-checked on loading (i.e. multiple 'default' values for taxo checkboxes). This is my first attempt at a more complex module, and I've already done a lot of searching but have so far been unable to find anything on this specific problem. I think I've worked out getting the ids into the session and using VBO's drupal_goto to send the view-user the form, but need help with setting those ID's as defaults in the webform on loading.

Answer (score 0):

It was actually pretty easy, in my case. Custom module with code to retrieve info from the session (not shown), then

```
function myModule_form_webform_client_form_[#]_alter( &$form, &$form_state, $form_id ){

  $box_options = $form['submitted']['box_ids'];
  $boxes = $_SESSION['boxes_from_session'];

  $arguments = set_checkboxes_function($boxes);
  if(!empty($arguments)){
      $box_options['#default_value'] = $arguments;
      unset($_SESSION['boxes_from_session']);
    }

      return $form;
}

function set_datasets_function($boxes){
  $default_vals = array();
  foreach($boxes as $item ) {
  // below code from suggestions here*
  // is overkill, this wants a 1D array
    //$key = $item->tid;
    //$value = $item->name;
    //$default_vals[$key] = $value;
    array_push($default_vals,$item->tid); 
  }
  //dpm($default_vals);
  return $default_vals;
}
```

*https://www.drupal.org/forum/support/module-development-and-code-questions/2008-02-28/how-to-check-default-value-in-form